# Area of a region R

Tags: geometry, 3d, coordinate-systems, area

For a point $P$ in the plane, let $d_1(P)$ and $d_2(P)$ be the distances of the point $P$ from the lines $x-y=0$ and $x+y=0$ respectively. The area of the region $R$ consisting of all the points $P$ lying in the first quadrant of the plane and satisfying 
 $$2\le d_1(P) + d_2(P) \le 4$$ 
I am unable to understand how to proceed to solve the question. 
If the point was not situated on a plane would there be any change in the answer?

Comment: What have you tried so far? What are your thoughts? You have tried to solve it yourself haven't you? One approach would be to find a closed form of $d_1$ and $d_2$, try rotate the system to make the lines $x-y=0$ and $x+y=0$ horizontal respectively vertical.

Comment: I have tried it but I didn't get anywhere.. I didn't find the region ..so I can't find the area. I thought that we should from a general equation of plane and try to find the relation between the points from the date but there we many variables and less conditions

Answer (score 1):

The first diagram shows the coordinate system with the graphs of $x+y=0$ and $x-y=0$ sketched as dashed lines. The polygon $ABCD$ is a square centered at the origin with sides parallel to the coordinate axes and the point $P$ is a point on the square lying a positive distance $d_1$ from the line $x+y=0$ and a positive distance $d_2$ from the line $x-y=0$.

[image: Figure for proposition]

Proposition: The area of square $ABCD$ is given by $\mathscr{A}=2(d_1+d_2)^2$

Proof:

1. $PB=\sqrt{2}d_1$
2. $AP=\sqrt{2}d_2$
3. $AB=AP+PB=\sqrt{2}(d_1+d_2)$
4. $\mathscr{A}=2(d_1+d_2)^2$

The second diagram shows two concentric squares centered at the origin with sides parallel to the axes.
[image: Area of R]

The outer square has sides of length $4\sqrt{2}$ and the inner square has sides of length $2\sqrt{2}$.

From the proposition above it follows that for any point $P$ lying on the outer square, $d_1+d_2=4$ and that for any point $P$ lying on the inner square, $d_1+d_2=2$. For any point $P$ lying on or outside the inner square but on or inside the outer square, it will be the case that

$$ 2\le d_1+d_2\le 4 $$

Furthermore, the area of the region lying outside the smaller square but inside the larger square will be the difference of their areas:

\begin{eqnarray}
\mathscr{A}_{outer}-\mathscr{A}_{inner}&=&2(4)^2-2(2)^2\\
&=&24
\end{eqnarray}

Since the problem asks only the area of the portion lying within the first quadrant, indicated by the polygon $R=LKDJIH$, the correct answer is that the area of $R$ is 6.

Comment: How are d1(P) and d2(P) coordinates? I didn't understand that part and how did you conclude that the these are coordinates when the axes is rotated?

Comment: The lines $y=-x$ and $y=x$ are two lines intersecting at right angles and the point $P$ lies at a distance $d_1$ from one and $d_2$ from the other. So $(d_1,d_2)$ are the coordinates of $P$ in that coordinate system.

Comment: Also. How did you find the equivalent of the area to be the area bounded by the y axis ,y=x,x+y=4 and x+y=2 also is there any other approach to this question or is this the only way?

Comment: If you rotate the first figure $45^\circ$ counter-clockwise about $(0,0)$ you will have the second figure.

Comment: The general subject of rotation of coordinates involves trigonometry and matrices. Since I did not see those tags on the question I gave a geometrical explanation.

Comment: Also how did you find the equation of the lines?

Comment: Give me 30 minutes and I will try to modify my answer to make it easier for you to understand.

Comment: Sure I'll wait.

Comment: I'm sorry, I was interrupted by a visitor. I will try again later. But you may look here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_of_axes

Comment: I have reworked the problem using simple geometry without rotation of axes and as a result found the correct answer, whereas my first answer was half of what the correct answer should have been.

Comment: I know the answer it is 6

Comment: Yes, it is $6$, just as I said.

Comment: But I still wanted to know how did you find the equation of the lines?

Comment: Do you mean the lines forming the four sides of the square?

Comment: No. I meant in the previous approach.. I didn't understand how did you get x+y=4,x+y=2

Comment: We have two perpendicular lines $y=x$ and $y=-x$ and a point $P$ a positive distance $d_1$ from $y=x$ and a distance $d_2$ from $y=-x$. This is just like having a point $P(x,y)$ lying a distance $x$ from the $y$-axis and a distance $y$ from the $x$-axis with $2\le x+y\le 4$. Then $P$ would have to lie on or between the lines $x+y=2$ and $x+y=4$. If you specified that the distances must be positive, then you would find that $P$ would have to lie between or on the "diamonds" $|x|+|y|=2$ and $|x|+|y|=4$. Try sketching these two diamonds and then rotating them $45^\circ$. You will see the squares.

Comment: Yes. I see them now.